# A map from $S^{1}\times\cdots\times S^{1}$ to $S^{n}$ with nonzero degree

Tags: algebraic-topology

Can you construct a map 
$$F: S^{1}\times\cdots\times S^{1}(n~\text{copies of}~S^{1})\rightarrow S^{n}$$ 
of nonzero degree?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider a small standard closed ball $B$ in your torus $T$, and let $F$ be the complement in $T$ of the interior of $B$. Contracting $F$ to a point gives us a map $T\to T/F\cong S^n$.

What is its degree?

Comment: You mean contracting $F$ to a point? Then almost every point of $S^{n}$ has preimage of a point in $B$, and this map is a local homeomorphism near this point, so the degree is $\pm 1$. Am I right?

Comment: So this method can actually show that there exists maps of any degree, right? You just need to find disjoint balls in the torus. And the domain can be any n-dimensional manifold?

Comment: Since there exist maps $S^n\to S^n$ of any degree, composing them with mine give you maps $T\to S^n$ of any degree.

Comment: You are right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1 So this seems to work for any compact $n$-dimensional orientable manifold. Beautifully simple: thanks for sharing !